# How to check validation in OR conditions in yii2?

Tags: validation, yii2, client-side

I have two radio buttons and two textInput: `personID` and `otherPerson` in my form. users should select first radio and then fill personID textInput or choose second radio then `otherPerson` textInput will enable and can fill `otherPerson`. there is just one choice at the same time and filling one of them is necessary.

How to check required validation in client side? if first radio is enabled, `personID` is necessary and otherwise `otherPerson`. I've tried by follow codes, but it doentn't work.

```
 ['personID', 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
        return $model->rdPerson== 0;
    }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
        return $('input[name=rdPerson]').val()==0;
    }"]

 ['otherPerson', 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
            return $model->rdPerson== 1;
        }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
            return $('input[name=rdPerson]').val()==1;
        }"]
```

How to solve this problem?

my form:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'rdPerson')->radio(['name' => 'rdPerson', 'value' => 0]); ?>
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'personID')->textInput(); ?>


<?= $form->field($model, 'rdPerson')->radio(['name' => 'rdPerson', 'value' => 1])?>
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'otherPerson')->textInput(); ?>
```

Comment: Code looks ok. You need to `enableAjaxValidation` of form and replace `input[name=radio]` with `input_id` if possible.

Comment: can you add the form code where you are creating the inputs and the radio buttons?

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam I've edited my post and add what you need.

Comment: added an answer see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some changes to your form field and the script you are using inside the `whenClient`, donot provide the input names manually as they are generated by `ActiveForm` automatically, change your fields definition to use grouped radio buttons which mean rather than using `name='rdPerson'` or `$form->field($model,'rdPerson')` use array names to group them like `$form->field($model,'rdPerson[]')`. Because otherwise the way you are using it it will always retrieve the first radio button whenever your `whenClient` is triggered for either fields `personId` or `otherPerson`, and hence wont work.

Also inside `whenClient` you should check for the value of the `:checked` radio button rather than accessing the `.val()` directly, so that the `checked` radio button's value is retrieved.

Change you form fields to

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'rdPerson[]')->radio(['value' => 0,'uncheck'=>null]); ?>
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'personID')->textInput(); ?>


<?= $form->field($model, 'rdPerson[]')->radio(['value' => 1,'uncheck'=>null]) ?>
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'otherPerson')->textInput(); ?>
```

and update your model rules to below

```
[['personID'], 'required', 'when' => function($model, $attribute) {
        return $model->rdPerson == 0;
    },
    'whenClient' => 'function(attribute,value){ return ($("input[name=\''.\yii\helpers\Html::getInputName($this, 'rdPerson[]').'\']:checked").val()==0)}'],
[['otherPerson'], 'required', 'when' => function($model, $attribute) {
        return $model->rdPerson == 1;                    
    }, 'whenClient' => 'function(attribute,value){ return ($("input[name=\''.\yii\helpers\Html::getInputName($this,'rdPerson[]').'\']:checked").val()==1)}'],
```

Hope this helps you out.